# Send <input> value with onclick="", syntax failing

Tags: php, jquery, html

In my school project I need to be able to update information on hotel rooms. So I have a form, generated from my DB with PHP. And i need to take one value from an `<input>` field, and send it to my server-side code using AJAX, triggered by an  `onclick` handler.

This is my php code. Its the `id='newinfo'` that I want to send when I'm clicking on the `div` with `id='update_btn'`. For some reason, `$("#update_btn").on("click", newinfo);`
is not working.

```
    echo "<form class='edit_form' method='post' action=''>";
    echo "<input placeholder='New info here' type='text' id='newinfo' name='newinfo'/>";
    echo "<div id='update_btn' onclick='newinfo( " . $gr_display['id'] . " )'> Update room info </div>";
    echo "</form>";
```

This i my JS

```
function newinfo(id, newinfo) { 
console.log('Click, click');
}
```

Can someone help me with the syntax of the `onclick=""` for the 'div'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#update_btn", function(){
  console.log('Click, click');
});
```

Comment: that worked, i now i can get the new info like this 
       var newinfo=$("#newinfo").val();

Any ide how i can pass along the id as well?

Comment: @mackeemackee Sorry, didn't get you. Please explain.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "#update_btn", function(){

   var newinfo=$("#newinfo").val();
 console.log('Click, click', newinfo, id);
});`

This is my js code now, and if u look at my code at the top, u see that i had an id(so im changing the correct room and not all of them).

Comment: i found a solution `echo "<input id='form_id' type='hidden' value='" . $gr_display['id'] . "' />";

Thx alot man!`

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This single '' instead of double ""

```
onclick='newinfo( ' . $gr_display['id'] . ' )'>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a missing semicolon, try this instead:

```
<div id='update_btn' onclick='newinfo( " . $gr_display['id'] . " );' /> 
  Update room info 
</div>
```